# Advanced Batch Calculations

Tags: excel

i have a table with the columns:

**Start time** (A) - **End time** (B) - **Resting** (C)

Now i have different values in A, B and C, and all those values are entered manually (and i can't change them due to the restrictions to have either a value or a formula).
Now i want to make a batch operation to

1. Check if value of **C** is under a minimum
2. If yes, then set it to a
   minimum and add half of its distance to the minimum value to both **A** and **B**

**Example - Input** (Minimum is *01:00*)

```
10:00 - 20:00 - 00:00
11:00 - 22:00 - 01:00
09:00 - 19:00 - 00:30
```

**Example - Output**

```
10:30 - 20:30 - 01:00
11:00 - 22:00 - 01:00
09:15 - 19:30 - 01:00
```

I've heard about scripts being able to run inside Excel but only found a little amount of examples, and those few ones aren't well documentated!

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Comment: `and those few ones aren't well documentated!` - http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html

Comment: Yeah, googling for "excel batch calculations" gives mostly bad results, "excel vba" appears to be the right keyword. Diving in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this macro a try:

```
Sub TimeFixer()
    Dim N As Long, a As Date, b As Date
    Dim c As Date, e As Date, delta As Date
    Dim incr As Date
    incr = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "C").Value < incr Then
            delta = (incr - Cells(i, "C").Value) / 2
            Cells(i, "C").Value = incr
            Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value + delta
            Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value + delta
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect work! As this was only the basic concept, i customized it for my exact needs. Nevertheless, i want to check if A is under a different minimum and if so, add everything to B. I got the idea to create a timeserial(8,0,0) f.e. and compare it like you did, but it doesn't catch the right values. Using TimeValue on the TimeSerial doesn't convert it to an int either. Any ideas? Whole Code is here: http://pastebin.com/kjUnjU8E